# How do I access Enums using rJava?

Tags: java, r, rjava

I'm using a third-party library called [CDK](http://cdk.github.io/cdk/1.5/docs/api/index.html). I'm trying to create an instance of the class `Bond` using `rJava`:

```
o1 <- .jnew("org.openscience.cdk.Atom","O")
o2 <- .jnew("org.openscience.cdk.Atom","O")
J("org.openscience.cdk.Bond",o1,o2,
  "org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond.Order.SINGLE")
```

The problem is there is an Enum defined in this interfaced `IBond`, I need to pass it as an argument to the constructor `Bond(IAtom atom1, IAtom atom2, IBond.Order order)` but I don't know how to do this using `rJava`.

I tried

```
J("org.openscience.cdk.Bond",o1,o2,
  J("org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond.Order")$SINGLE)
```

hoping `SINGLE` could be accessed like any other static field/method but it didn't work.

Is there any way to pass Enum to methods using rJava?

Comment: did you ever manage to get CDK Bond creation working? I am encountering errors trying to create CDK molecules from R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the way to do this, I use the dollar sign to refer to the public Enum `Order` declared in the `IBond` interface and then another dollar sign to access the enum value:

```
J("org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond")$Order$SINGLE
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a nested class so the proper name is `org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order`:

```
> .jfields("org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order")
[1] "public static final org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order.SINGLE"   
[2] "public static final org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order.DOUBLE"   
[3] "public static final org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order.TRIPLE"   
[4] "public static final org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order.QUADRUPLE"
[5] "public static final org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order.QUINTUPLE"
[6] "public static final org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order.SEXTUPLE" 
[7] "public static final org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order.UNSET"
```

so the "normal" way would be either of

```
> .jfield("org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order",,"SINGLE")
[1] "Java-Object{SINGLE}"
> J("org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order")$SINGLE
[1] "Java-Object{SINGLE}"
```